# whats the '?' in code

Tags: java, android, ternary-operator

can someone explain these code? why does it have `?` in there?

```
package course.examples.theanswer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TheAnswer extends Activity {

public static final int[] answers = { 42, -10, 0, 100, 1000 };
public static final int answer = 42;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.answer_layout);

    TextView answerView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer_view);


    int val = findAnswer();
    String output = (val == answer) ? "42" : "We may never know";
    answerView.setText("The answer to life, the universe and everything is:\n\n"
                    + output);
}

private int findAnswer() {
    for (int val : answers) {
        if (val == answer)
            return val;
    }
    return -1;
}
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F: - damn, there's a bug in SO link creation in comments...

Comment: Ternary operator. It means `if(val == answer) { output = "42"; } else { output = "We may never know"; }`.

Comment: It's the conditional operator: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25

Comment: thanks for the answers guys, and sorry I couldnt find the '?' question before

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its *conditional / ternary* operator.

```
String output = (val == answer) ? "42" : "We may never know";
```

effectively same as :

```
if(val==answer)
{
 output = "42" 
}

else
{
output = "we may never know"
}
```

Comment: Force OP to use curly braces.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - yes.. You are right.. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is called a `Ternary operator`. It's a kind of Replacement for `if-else` statement.

```
(Condition) ? {if true execute this} : {else do this}
```

Comment: *{if true execute this} : {else do this}* It does not just execute, it ***assigns***

Answer (score 1):

It's a ternary operator..

this line:

```
String output = (val == answer) ? "42" : "We may never know";
```

is the same as this:

```
String output;
if (val == answer) {
  output = "42";
} else {
  output = "We may never know";
}
```

It is usually used for simple conditions and assignments...a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

`?:` is operator for `if-then-else` behavior

```
(val == answer) ? "42" : "We may never know";
```

this means

```
if(val==answer) {
    output = "42"
} else { 
     output = "We may never know";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean this line:

```
String output = (val == answer) ? "42" : "We may never know";
    answerView.setText("The answer to life, the universe and everything is:\n\n"
                    + output);
```

This `?` is a short form of (if...then...else).

if (val == answer) then output  = "42" else  output  = "We may never know";
        answerView.setText("The answer to life, the universe and everything is:\n\n"
                        + output)

Answer (score 1):

On this line

```
String output = (val == answer) ? "42" : "We may never know";
```

the ? represents the ternary operator: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

if val == answer is true, the value assigned to output will be "42". If it equates to false, it will be assigned "We may never know"

```
val = answer;
...
String output = (val == answer) ? "42" : "We may never know";
System.out.println(output);
```

would output:

> 42

whereas:

```
val = answer + 1;
...
String output = (val == answer) ? "42" : "We may never know";
System.out.println(output);
```

would output:

> We may never know